# Как лучше всего сверстать элемент

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильнее и лучше сверстать серую боковую линию с использованием Bootstrap 3? Она должна изменять свою ширину в зависимости от размера экрана. Спасибо заранее.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Bootstrap 3 уже прошлый век используйте 4-ю версию

Comment: Bootstrap в принципе прошлый век, используйте чистый css))

Answer (score 0):

Если у "серой линии" только декоративная функция, то:

```
html: {
  padding: 0 0 0 50px;
  background-color: #3f3f3f;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, использовал этот вариант)

Answer (score 0):

1. `background-color: #cccccc;`
2. `border: 1px solid #cccccc;`
3. `border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;`
4. `border-bottom: 1px solid #9e9e9e;`